# How can I toggle a submenu on ipad touch?

Tags: jquery, ipad

I want to toggle hide and show a submenu on ipad touch. But my code is not working:

```
<ul class="menu">

<li class="menu-item-has-submenu"><a><span>fruits</span></a></li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="">strawberry</a></li>
    <li><a href="">orange</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The aler text is not appearing.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

function isTouchDevice() {
    return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
}
if (isTouchDevice() === true) {
$(".sub-menu").hide();


$(".menu-item-has-submenu").bind("click touchstart", function(){
  alert("This was clicked.");
  $(".sub-menu").toggle();

  }      
} 

});


</script>
```

Do you know what I did wrong?